# How to fix bootstrap datepicker when it show letters instead of numbers?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datepicker, slim-lang

I have tried searching through many forums but found nothing. Maybe I used wrong keywords.
I used a button to display datepicker, I noticed that at first, it displayed correctly, but after about 0.1 sec, it became like this

[It shows letters and numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adC0h.png)
I also noticed one time that one number in my page was converted to letter, too.

I'm pretty sure other functions work fine. The code has nothing to show, too, but I will show some lines

```
button#some_button.btn.btn-primary type ="button" data-date= someday data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"  Edit
javascript:
  $('#some_button').datepicker().on('changeDate', function(ev){
    $('#some_button').datepicker('hide');
    var newdate = new Date(ev.date.valueOf());
    ...
```

Is this slim-lang related? 
Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was caused by google translate. There was inconsistencies in the language: the page was in Japanese while the datepicker was in English. When Chrome automaticly translated the page, it caused that error (that's why it only showed correctly in the first 0.1s)